# IntelliJ wants to create new classes under test root instead of main

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a new class "VittuSaatana" by pressing alt+enter on `new VittuSaatana();`.

[image]

I get the new class creation popup but it has the test root selected and the following error message:

`Test root is selected while the source root is expected`

Googling that only results in hits from IntelliJ source so yeah no idea what that means.

Even when I set the source root as main, it will still create the `VittuSaatana` class under `myproject/src/test/java/foopackage/VittuSaatana.java` instead of `myproject/src/foopackage/VittuSaatana.java`

Things work on other projects so I'd assume this has something to do with project settings - however I cannot spot any differences in the settings between this one and ones that work fine. Also when I create classes via ctrl+shift+insert it creates them in the correct source root.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as your source root? It sounds like `src/`, but if you're using the Standard Directory Layout it should be `src/main/java/`.

Comment: If its a maven project, try to nuke the .idea folder and recreate project from pom.xml

Comment: By the way you shouldn't swear - Vittu and Saatana are NOT nice words in Finnish ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve I thought that'd slip by. The actual issue disappeared  when I booted intellij so must've been some weird glitch.